# Dropping controls onto controls in the Visual Studio WPF designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am used to the Windows Forms designer and now for the first time using the WPF designer in Visual Studio 2010. I read that you can just drop the controls you want onto your form. In my case, controls dragged from the Toolbox don't drop like I expect them to.

Two examples: some controls should do special things, like the GridSplitter [snapping](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html#resize) to the nearest gridline when dropped. But mine just stays a gray rectangle at the position on the Grid where I dropped it.
I'm also using Microsoft's WPF Ribbon control (in a RibbonWindow), and they say that [dropping a RibbonGroup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/add-more-content-to-my-simple-ribbon-application.aspx) onto the Ribbon adds it to the Ribbon. But mine is put on the underlying Grid where I dropped it, no matter what control I select before dropping a control.

I've been searching the web but found only answers to questions about drag-and-drop in running WPF applications. Am I misunderstanding the behavior of the WPF designer, or is there an actual problem here?

---

To reproduce: create a new WPF project, divide the existing Grid in two by clicking the Grid's top bar. Drag and drop a GridSplitter onto one of the cells. My result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio WPF designer does behave differently from the Windows Forms designer, as you've discovered.

When you drag an element to the designer or add it by double-clicking the element in the toolbox, the designer creates it at a default size.  In your case the size is 100px by 10px.  Try it with other controls, you'll see each one has a different size.

When you drag to the designer, the location is determined by the location of your mouse when you release the left mouse button.  Since you are dragging into grid (which doesn't support absolute positioning) the location is achieved by setting the margin property on the grid splitter.  For your example, of course, you don't want the margins or size set. Unfortunately, there is no way to change this behavior in this means that you have to constantly delete the margins and width-height property settings.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF designer in VS2010 is a bit Clunky.  Expression Blend would be a better choice for WYSIWYG design (or the next, currently unreleased, version of VS which integrates Blend into VS). XAML is a grid based layout system so controls you add will tend to snap to the side of whatever container they are in.  That can sometimes not act the way you'd like it if the designer automatically applies properties like Border and Margin.  If you delete those and correctly set the height, width, and alignment properties, the divider and splitter should show up properly.

Also VS2010 sometimes seems to get confused about where you're actually adding a control.  The easiest solution for the interim is to leverage the split view and cut/paste the XAML for the control you added into the content/container control you intended it to go into.

Whenever I'm stuck with VS2010, I just hand code all my XAML.  I find it to be a good deal faster than using the designer.

Comment: So you are saying that there _is_ a problem with the WPF designer in Visual Studio, but that everyone seems to use Blend (as I couldn't find anyone mentioning this) and that all sources telling me to drop controls also expect me to use Blend? Nice... :P

Comment: Contrary to what Max said, WPF is NOT a grid based layout system.  Expression Blend and Visual Studio designers add a default grid to every new Window, but that is an artifact of their IDE's.  You can easily change the root element to any other WPF panel.

Comment: Yes, some developers use the Expression Blend designer as a replacement for the one included in VS. In my opinion, Expression Blend is superior to the Visual Studio designer in many areas. I typically work with both IDEs open.  As Max said, the Visual Studio/Expression Blend team are creating a shared designer for the next release of VS.

Comment: You're not expected or required to use anything (you could use notepad if you wanted) but Blend is a superior tool than the built in VS designer.  In terms of it being a grid layout system, you're right that it's not technically accurate but it's the best way I could describe the difference between it and WinForms.